# Cannot access tomcat from mac within local network

Tags: linux

I have tomcat running at

192.168.100.3:8080

on centos 7. On centos I can access it and I can also access on mobile phone connected via the same local wifi network but I cannot access it from Mac also on the same wifi local network and get this error:

This site can’t be reached
192.168.l00.3’s server IP address could not be found.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your mac is on the same network as the server?

Comment: Have you tested via ping to see if there is lower layer network connectivity between the servers.  If there is a long delay or timeout then suspect either side has a firewall running which may be impeding the network traffic.

Comment: ping 192.168.100.3   works fine from mac with zero packet loss. Yes mac is  just sitting next to centos desktop on the same router/wifi network.

Comment: You've pasted in an "i" instead of a 1 for the IP. Is that the same as in the web browser? If so that's not going to work.